# What is required for EF Core's IMethodCallTranslator to work with `EF.Functions` to provide a custom function?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to implement a custom `IMethodCallTranslator` in EF Core 3.1 with the Sqlite provider.

I have created:

1. An extension method off of `this DbFunctions` *which is called at query time*
2. An implementation of `IMethodCallTranslator` *which is `Translate` not called*
3. A derived `RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider` which I'm passing an instance of my `IMethodCallTranslator`. This constructor *is* hit. I also tried overriding `RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider.Translate` and this was not hit.
4. An implementation of `IDbContextOptionsExtension` (and its info class) which registers the `RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider` as a singleton `IMethodCallTranslatorProvider`.

All of this is added via `OnConfiguring` by getting the `IDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure` form of the options.

Am I missing something? I've tried following: https://github.com/tkhadimullin/ef-core-custom-functions/tree/feature/ef-3.1-version in my code, yet it's invoking the extension method, not my translator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can't pass a reference to your full entity class to the function for further processing:

Doesn't work:

```
public static string DoWork(this DbFunctions _, object entity, string key)
//...
dbContext.Items.Select(i => new { Entity = i, String = EF.Functions.DoWork(i, i.StringValue) });
```

Where this will:

```
public static string DoWork(this DbFunctions _, string key)
//...
dbContext.Items.Select(i => new { Entity = i, String = EF.Functions.DoWork(i.StringValue) });
```

Also, generics *are* supported so it would be a nice way to introspect call and get the type of the entity for the model in a `RelationalMethodCallTranslatorProvider`.

```
public static string DoWork<T>(this DbFunctions _, string key)
//...
dbContext.Items.Select(i => new { Entity = i, String = EF.Functions.DoWork<Item>(i.StringValue) });
```