# How to incorporate an Expression<> into an Entity Framework query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to write a class that helps create a LINQ query dynamically.

```
protected Func<T, TColumn> GetColumn;

public MyClass(Func<T, TColumn> getColumn)
{
    GetColumn = getColumn;
}

public virtual IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    if (FilterMode == FilterModeMatchAny)
        return query.Where(x => FilterIds.Contains(GetColumn(x)));
    return query;
}
```

This class is called like this:

```
MyClass<Location, string> myClass = new MyClass<Location, string>(l => l.State);

var locations = myClass.ApplyFilter(DbContext.Locations);
```

However, the code above fails:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> .Where(l => Invoke(__GetJoiningTables_0, l[Location])
> .Any(xx => __FilterIds_1
> .Contains(Invoke(__GetColumn_2, xx)
> )))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

The trouble appears to be the way I'm using `GetColumn`. So I changed the declaration of `GetColumn` so that it is now an expression.

```
protected Expression<Func<T, TColumn>> GetColumn;
```

The same argument being passed to my constructor can easily be converted to this type. I Only need to change the argument type.

But now how can I use this new `GetColumn` in my `ApplyFilter()` method?

**Update:**

Eventually, I also need to do the same thing to the following two expressions.

```
// Expressions to incorporate
protected Expression<Func<T, ICollection<TJoinTable>>> GetJoiningTables;
protected new Expression<Func<TJoinTable, TColumn>> GetColumn;

// Match any query
return query.Where(x => GetJoiningTables(x).Any(xx => FilterIds.Contains(GetColumn(xx))));

// Match all query
return query.Where(x => GetJoiningTables(x).Count(xx => FilterIds.Contains(GetColumn(xx))) >= FilterIds.Count());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to keep the column as an expression, or c# will compile the lambda function and EF will be unable to extract which column it is;

```
protected Expression<Func<T, TColumn>> GetColumn;

public MyClass(Expression<Func<T, TColumn>> getColumn)
{
    GetColumn = getColumn;
}
```

Now, you could use the static methods of `Expression` to build an entire filter expression by hand. But in your case there's a shortcut. Since you can reuse the parameter and body of the input expression (eg `x => x.Column`), and wrap it in your `Contains` call (eg `x => FilterIds.Contains(x.Column)`).

**EDIT:**

Since you've now revealed that `FilterIds` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, then `FilterIds.Contains()` is actually the static extension method `Enumerable.Contains()`. The simplest way to find a matching generic static method is to create a matching delegate.

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    if (FilterMode == FilterModeMatchAny)
        return query.Where(
            Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
                Expression.Call(
                    null,
                    new Func<IEnumerable<TColumn>,TColumn,bool>(Enumerable.Contains).Method,
                    Expression.Constant(FilterIds),
                    GetColumn.Body),
                GetColumn.Parameters)
        );
    return query;
}
```

**EDIT:**

`.Where(x => GetJoiningTables(x).Any(...`

Ok that's a can of worms.... I assume that what you're trying to do here is take a collection of navigations to other tables & columns, and apply a filter to that?

I find it helps to build an example `Expression` that you're trying to achieve. I assume you're trying to build expressions like;

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter = t => 
    Enumerable.Any(t.Child1, c => FilterIds.Contains(c.ChildCol))
    || Enumerable.Any(t.Child2, c => FilterIds.Contains(c.OtherChildCol))
    ... ;

Expression<Func<T,bool>> filter = t => 
    Enumerable.Count(t.Child1, c => FilterIds.Contains(c.ChildCol))
    + Enumerable.Count(t.Child2, c => FilterIds.Contains(c.OtherChildCol))
    ... ;
```

I suggest that you write this code, let the c# compiler turn them into `Expression` graphs, and use the debugger to see what those graphs look like.

If possible, I'd recommend trying to find a way to "give to cesar what is caesar's". And assemble fragments of `Expression`s by inlining or transforming some template `Expression`.

Comment: Thanks. However `FilterIds.GetType().GetMethod("Contains")` is returning `null`. (Note that `FilterIds` is not `null`.)

Comment: Either needs the right binding flags, or the right argument types. You didn't define `FilterIds` and I didn't test it.

Comment: `FilterIds` is of type `IEnumerable<T>`, where `T` is `string` in this case. The `Contains` method is part of `Enumerable`. So I can use `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod("Contains")`, but that returns an ambiguous match exception. And good luck trying to figure out the type parameters to a generic extension method. What a pain!

Comment: Ah, that's not `FilterIds.Contains` then, it's the static extension method `Enumerable.Contains(FilterIds, ...)`, updating answer.

Comment: Damn! That works. Not sure I can even understand it but I'll dig deeper. I need to add a few more. Thanks!

Comment: If you're doing something like this a lot, you could try this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62687811/how-can-i-convert-a-custom-function-to-a-sql-expression-for-entity-framework-cor/62708275#62708275

Comment: FYI, I first saw the delegate trick in `GetMethodInfo` here; https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs#L45 (note that the actual delegate creation is implicit)

Comment: I've been programming for decades and have written some fairly sophisticated code. But understanding the these expressions need to be written is coming slowly to me. I looked at your other link, but am not sure what is happening there and wouldn't want to do anything that could break in a future release. What would you charge me to convert two additional, somewhat more complex expressions like you did above? I've added them to my question if you want to see.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. As much as I love this approach, it's just getting a little too hairy for comfort, and a workaround isn't too bad. If you'd like to earn a few more points, perhaps you could look at my [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879661/applying-an-expression-to-a-linq-where-clause) to this. I know I need to use `Expression.Lambda<>` somehow but I can't seem to find the right syntax.